# Adjusting the height to the number of elements in the flex-direction

Tags: css, flexbox, display

I'm having trouble setting the height for elements.
I come across an object that sometimes has 6 elements and sometimes only 2.
I would like it to always calculate the height in such a way that the tiles are displayed in 3 columns.

When there are 5 objects or less, two columns are displayed, but when 6 objects have a lot of content, one of them is cut off and only 5 are displayed.

The maximum number of objects that can come is 6.

How to make objects in the flex-direction: column position always be displayed and always have three columns and the height is adjusted automatically?

```css
   .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .w3 {
        width: 33%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="w3">
            <ul>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="w3"> <ul>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
            </ul></div>
        <div class="w3"> <ul>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
            </ul></div>
        <div class="w3"> <ul>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
            </ul></div>
        <div class="w3"> <ul>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
            </ul></div>
        <div class="w3"> <ul>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
                <li>3242</li>
            </ul></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and edit the code snippet to demonstrate the **problem**. You can also include hand-drawn diagrams to illustrate how you want it to look/work.